# Split text at line end: ignoring inline \n

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, line

I have some text with `START` and `END` tags something like:

```
SOURCE = '''
Text with \n \n and some more # an so ..

other text to be ignored
START
docu \n this text \n I need includive the capital start and end
but do not split \n \n only split at the actuall end of the line
END

gfsdfgadgfg \n\n\n \n
5 635634
START
similar # to the above I need \n all of this in the split line
but do not split \n \n only split at the actuall end of the line
END


more text to ignore
'''
```

And hope to prase it to something like

```
parts_splitted_by_actual_end_of_line = {
'Part1_lines' : 
['START',
'docu \n this text \n I need includive the capital start and end',
'but do not split \n \n only split at the actuall end of the line',
'END'],

'Part1_lines' : 
['START',
'similar # to the above I need \n all of this in the split line',
'but do not split \n \n only split at the actuall end of the line',
'END'],
}
```

I can find the `START` and `END` tags with string find and extract the text between.

**But I'm completely stuck to split the lines keeping the `\n` within the line ?**

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect Python to be able to tell the difference between the `\n` in the text and the `\n` at the end of the line?

Comment: If the text contents are copied (copy + paste) from a file, just prepend `r` to the string literal to make it a raw string: `r'''my string contents'''`. This will separate the `\n` from the actual newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a raw string.  Add a r prefix before your string literal like this:

```
SOURCE = r'''Insert text here\n'''
```

This will do the escaping of your newline character for you.

To unescape it later afterwards (probably after your split), take the string and decode it like this:

```
string = string.decode('string_escape')
```